# Ordering of Products in "Anchored" Categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

The ordering of the products for a category is plainly set through the Admin for a standard category, but when you "Anchor" the category it seems as if it loses all sense of the manually set order.  It seems to default to the order that the products were entered in.  Is there a way to set the order of the products when the category is anchored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to "cleverly" set product sorting from children categories of a parent anchored category. This is quite logical as some products may have the same position in siblings categories.

Having faced this problem many times, I've always ended to attaching all the products to the parent category and set the order to this category...

Comment: To overcome this, I've setup a "global_sort_order" attribute where every product gets it's own value and there are never duplicates. But still, Anchor categories with empty `product category` lists seem to do what they please.